# How do I access the single String field of the svg::node::Value tuple struct?

Tags: struct, rust, tuples

I am using the [svg crate](https://crates.io/crates/svg). I have a `svg::node::Value`, which is a tuple struct, and want to access its `.0` value. I wrote this, based on their [parsing example](https://docs.rs/svg/0.8.0/svg/#example-parsing):

```
for event in svg::open(path).unwrap() {
    match event {
        Event::Tag(Group, _, attributes) => {
            let val = attributes.get("inkscape:groupmode");
             if val.is_some(){
                let val = val.unwrap();
                let s = value.0;
            } 
        }
        _ => {}
    }
```

The compiler complains about the `.0` field being private **rustc(E0616)**.

```
ERROR: field `0` of struct `svg::node::value::Value` is private rustc(E0616)
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: `if x.is_some(); { let y = x.unwrap() }` ==> `if let Some(y) = x {}`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "access"? Do you wish to take ownership of the `String`, mutate it, or just read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svg::node::Value` [implements `Deref<Target = str>`](https://docs.rs/svg/0.8.0/svg/node/struct.Value.html#impl-Deref), which means you can write:

```
let s: &str = &*value;
```

(Both the `&str` type and the `*` dereference are optional. I wrote them out to be explicit. If you omit them they'll be inserted automatically.)